# poetry publish from codebuild to aws codeartifact fails with UploadError

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake, aws-databricks

I have a dataset I need to periodically import to my datalake, replacing current dataset
After I produce a dataframe I currently do:

```scala
df.write.format("delta").save("dbfs:/mnt/defaultDatalake/datasets/datasources")
```

But if I run the job again I get the following error:

```
AnalysisException: dbfs:/mnt/defaultDatalake/datasets/insights/datasources already exists.;
```

While I know I can do a `dbutils.fs.rm` before, I'd rather just "replace" the data there
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [overwrite mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#save-modes):

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(....)
```

If new dataframe has different schema, then you may need to add `.option("overwriteSchema", "true")` as well (see this [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/24/diving-into-delta-lake-schema-enforcement-evolution.html) for more information)

Comment: Lol, I've missed that. Thanks!